# Get request API

Tags: python, get, request, python-requests

I use API:

https://www.blockchain.com/api/q

Trying to make a Get request:

```
url = 'https://www.blockchain.info/api/q/getreceivedbyaddress/' + strpod + '?confirmations=6'
zapros = requests.get(url)
```

But it returns the entire page.

And I only need the balance value.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
import requests 
address = "17LREmmnmTxCoFZ59wfhg4S639GsPqjTRT"
URL = "https://blockchain.info/q/getreceivedbyaddress/"+address+"?confirmations=6"
r = requests.get(url = URL) 
  
# extracting balance ((in satoshi))
bt_balance = r.json()
```

[image]

The API link is not wrong. Please check with the blockchain addresss

Comment: @vfddd32fdf I can able to capture the balance pls check it. https://imgur.com/0fnLS1o